# How to adapt map in order to find the nearest smaller object?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, tree

For example, if my map is from integers to doubles and contains :

- 2 -> 3.4
- 3 -> 87.3
- 5 -> 0.0
- 12 -> 43.4

When I search 4, I have to obtain 87.3, since 3 is the nearest smaller key which is in the map. When I search 11, I have to obtain 0.0.

This could be done with a balanced tree. But I don't want implement a balanced tree, may be there is a way to do this directly using STL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/). Depending on the exact state of the map, you might need to decrement the iterator (to get to the element actually smaller).

The overall complexity is logarithmic in any case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, next time I will read the documentation more carefully.